# Red terminal text on dark background hard to see on monitor

Tags: display

**Question**: how to make red terminal text on dark background NOT hard to see on my monitor?

I have an LG 43UD79-B 4K IPS Monitor. I connect both my Macbook Pro and a Ubuntu Desktop PC (via HDMI) to it. On Ubuntu, I noticed that the red text on black terminal background is extremely hard to read, as if the text are blended into the background.

Here's a photo demonstrating what I see:
[image]

And if I take a screenshot of the terminal window and:

1. view the screenshot image on the same monitor, same machine (Ubuntu), it looks same bad.
2. view the screenshot image on the **same monitor** but on Macbook, it looks much clearer:

[image]

I have tried to adjust font antialiasing settings, hinting, using different terminals, but none of that helps.

**Question**:

Comment: You may have a 4k monitor, but what res is it being driven at? What font is being used in each case?

Comment: Hi I think it’s nothing to do with a specific font. I tired several truetype and non truetype fonts. They all have similar issue.